# Where have the Scheduled Tasks gone to in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, scheduled-tasks

I cannot find Scheduled Tasks under control panel.
Where did they move it?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Open up the **Task Scheduler** by either typing "task" into the Start Menu search bar, or by opening **All Programs** > **Accesories** > **System Tools**

*Source: [How to Create a Automated Task that Runs at a Set Time in Windows 7](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/12444-task-scheduler-create-new-task.html)*

Comment: Geez Molly, is there anything you don't know? Can I get you on a retainer as my personal computer consultant? Lord knows I need one.

Answer (score 3):

Just like with anything else on Windows 7, you don't actually need to know where it is to use it. It is usually fastest to rather than finding it specifically, just use the search from the start menu.

Start typing "scheduled tasks" and by the time you type in "sch" it should already have appeared (depending on how fast you type and how fast your computer is).

Answer (score 1):

Scheduled Tasks are in:

```
%windir%\System32\Tasks
```

and

```
%systemroot%\Tasks
```

Only Administrator access is allowed, so if you don't wanna mess up the (NTFS) permissions use something like Total Commander & run it as admin (it's shareware, to use as long as you want :))

PS-

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb742547.aspx

Comment: Garrett, I'm fairly new to answering on superuser.com, but I can see that the link points to Windows 2000; not sure exactly what your edit included, although I can see some text below. I guess I will understand, once I read it over again; Hope everything was cool with my posting, tnx.